# Странности при работе с двумерным массивом в си

Tags: c

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void)
{
    int a[3][2] = {{10,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}};
    printf("%p\n", a[0]);
    printf("%p\n", (int *)a);
    printf("%p\n", *a);
    printf("%p\n", a); 
    printf("%p\n", &(a[0][0]));
    return 0;
}
```

Код выдает одно и то же число...
Особенно поражает то, что равны a и *a.
Что происходит?
И еще когда смотрю на *(int *)a, то получаю 10...

Comment: Многомерность массивов в Си — абстракция. В реальности это всего лишь косвенная адресация.

Comment: @0andriy: А какая многомерность не была бы "абстракцией"? В чем неполноценность "косвенной адресации" как натурального способа реализации многомерности?

Comment: @Ant, любая, которая реализована соотвествующим образом "в железе". Касательно второго вопроса мне непонятна ваша мотивация. Вы мне приписываете видимо что-то такое, о чём я не говорил, а потом пытаетесь опровергнуть якобы моё утверждение. Возможно пара выходных не помешает ;)

Comment: @0andriy Я ничего не приписываю, а лишь задаю обычный вопрос. Мне по-прежнему не ясно, какая реализация будет считаться "реализованной соответствующим образом". Вы хотите сказать, что для многомерного массива нужно "многомерное железо" или что-то другое? (Это тоже просто вопоос, никакого "приписывания")

Comment: Я не понимаю, почему такой вопрос возник, но я не знаю на него ответа. Подискутировать можно за рамками этого поста, я думаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вас не должно удивлять равенство `a` и `*a` в данном контексте. Нечего удивительного в этом нет. В языке С "двумерный массив" - это просто обычный одномерный массив, элементами которого тоже являются одномерные массивы.

Одномерный массив, скажем, `double d[10]` - это просто плоский непрерывный компактный блок памяти, размера `10 * sizeof(double)`, состоящий из десяти плотно лежащих друг за другом элементов типа `double`. При этом адрес всего массива `&d` численно совпадает с адресом его нулевого элемента `&d[0]`, ибо "начинаются" они в одной и той же точке памяти. Ситуация полностью аналогична равенству указателей вот в таком вот примере

```
struct S { int a; } s;

printf("%p %p\n", (void *) &s, (void *) &s.a);
// Оба указателя совпадают численно
```

Адрес всего объекта struct-типа численно совпадает с адресом самого первого поля внутри этого объекта. Совершенно аналогичным образом адрес всего массива численно совпадает с адресом самого первого (нулевого) элемента этого массива.

При этом в языке С выражение `d` типа "массив `double [10]`" в большинстве контекстов (не во всех) *неявно приводится* к типу `double *` - указателю, указывающему на нулевой элемент массива. Т.е. в большинстве контекстов выражение `d` ведет себя эквивалентно выражению `&d[0]`, т.е. массив внешне ведет себя как указатель. Это явление называют *array type decay*. (Именно по этой причине массивы в С часто путают с указателями, хотя на самом деле это разные типы и никаких указателей в массивах нет.)

Все это немедленно применимо и к двумерным массивам (и многомерным массивам), ибо, как сказано выше, в языке С "двумерный массив" - это рекурсивная по своему устройству структура: это просто одномерный массив, элементами которого являются одномерные массивы. Вышеупомянутое явление *array type decay* работает неизменным образом на любом уровне этой рекурсии.

Выше выражение `a` изначально имеет тип `int [3][2]`, но в данном контексте неявно приводится к типу "указатель на нулевой элемент массива `a`". Этот указатель имеет тип `int (*)[2]` и указывает на подмассив `a[0]` типа `int [2]` в составе `a`.

Выражение `*a` изначально имеет тип `int [2]` - это подмассив `a[0]` в составе `a`, но в данном контексте `*a` неявно приводится к типу "указатель на нулевой элемент массива `a[0]`". Это указатель типа `int *`, который указывает на самый первый `int` в составе подмассива `a[0]`, т.е. на `a[0][0]`.

И сам `a`, и `a[0]`, и `a[0][0]` начинаются в одной и той же точке памяти, по каковой причине числовые представления этих указателей совпадают

```
printf("%p %p %p\n", (void *) &a, (void *) a, (void *) *a);
// Все три указателя совпадают численно
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

*Возьмем тип `int` равный четырем байтам*

---

Давайте представим массив в памяти:

```
 +------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
 | Переменная | a[0][0]  | a[0][1]  | a[1][0]  | a[1][1]  |
 +------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
 | Адрес      | 0x61fe98 | 0x61fe9c | 0x61fea0 | 0x61fea4 |
 +------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
 | Значение   |      10  |       2  |       2  |       3  |
 +------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

В отладчике можно увидеть:

```
print &a => (int (*)[3][2]) 0x61fe98  // указатель на двумерный массив 
print a  => {{10, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}

print &(*a) => (int (*)[2]) 0x61fe98  // указатель на одномерный массив
print *a    => {10, 2}

print &(**a) => (int *) 0x61fe98      // указатель на целое число
print **a    =>  10
```

Как видим, адреса двумерного массива `a`, одномерного подмассива `a[0]` (`{10, 2}`) и первого элемента подмассива `a[0][0]` (`10`) равны. То есть:

```
&a == &(*a) == &(**a)
^     ^        ^     
|     |        | a[0][0] (первое значение первого подмассива двумерного массива)
|     |          
|     | a[0][] (первый подмассив двумерного массива)
|
| a[][] (весь двумерный массив)
```

Итак:

```
printf("%p\n", a[0]);          // 1. адрес первого подмассива двумерного массива (int (*)[2]) 0x61fe98
printf("%p\n", (int *)a);      // 2. адрес двумерного массива, просто 
                               //    приведенный к указателю, имеет тип (int*),
                               //    если разыменовать его получим 10
printf("%p\n", *a);            // 3. то же самое, что и 1
printf("%p\n", a);             // 4. не то же самое, что и 2! Имеет тот же 
                               //    адрес, но тип (int (*)[3][2])
printf("%p\n", &(a[0][0]));    // 5. Указатель на первый элемент подмассива 
                               //    двумерного массива, то же самое что и 2
```

Comment: Тогда, если a[i] = *(a+i) - почему мы получаем указатель на a[i][0]?

Comment: Я хочу сказать, если a - указатель на первый элемент массива, то получается *a = 10 должно быть, но получилось так, что *a =a

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.B2.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.B0.D0.B4.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F

Comment: @Eanmos, *a - это то, что лежит по адресу a, правильно же? Получается по этому адресу должен лежать указатель на начало массива, с другой стороны, как ты сказал, a указывает на начало двумерного массива, и я даже проверил *(int *)a == 10. Вот это меня и смутило... То есть с одной стороны по адресу a лежит указатель, с другой стороны по адресу a должен лежать первый элемент массива, и все зависит от приведения типов указателя...

Comment: @GeorgeKasparyants, обновил ответ.

Comment: @Eanmos: "a - это указатель на указатель" - это совершенно не верно. Откуда вы такое взяли? Выражение `a` имеет тип `int [3][2]` и, в случае неявного приведения к указательному типу дает тип `int (*)[2]`. Это **не** указатель на указатель. Это указатель на массив `int [2]`.

Comment: @AnT, да, наверное Вы правы.

Comment: @George Kasparyants: "По адресу" не "лежит указатель". В структуре данных типа `int [3][2]` в языках С и С++ в вообще в принципе нет и не может быть никаких указателей. Любые указатели, которые возникают при работе с массивами - это воображаемые *промежуточные временные значения*, получаемые в результате *неявного приведения типа* от типа "массив" к типу "указатель". Эти указатели существуют только концептуально,  "в уме компилятора". Они нигде не хранятся в памяти, т.е. физически их нет. И "указывать" по этой причине на них никто не может.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%p\n", a[0]); // <- 1
printf("%p\n", (int *)a); // <- 2
printf("%p\n", *a); // <- 3
printf("%p\n", a); // <- 4
printf("%p\n", &(a[0][0])); // <- 5
```

Для того, чтобы понять, что происходит полезно понимать, что такое на самом деле массив. В С/C++ массив это обычный указатель на начало массива. Значения в массиве хранятся последовательно. Также на указателях есть [арифметика](http://proguroki.ru/urok7/urok7_1/urok7_1_6/urok-7-1-6-adresnaya-arifmetika). То есть если прибавить к указателю 1, то получим уаказатель на следующий элемент данного типа. Итак что же такое запись `a[i]` на самом деле эта запись эквивалентна следующей: `*(a+i)` то есть берём значение, которое хранится в `i`-ой ячейке после той, на которую указывает `a`. И на самом деле такая запись тоже допустима: `i[a]` (попробуйте, например вывести ещё `0[a]`). Итак `a[0] = *(a+0) = *a`.
Таким образом равенство 1 и 3 установили.
Теперь разберём, почему `a` и `*a` совпадают. На самом деле потому, что они указывают ровно в одно и тоже место. В памяти эти 6 чисел будут храниться последовательно: `{10, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4}`. Таким образом `a` указывающее на весь этот массив и `a[0]` указывающее на кусок `{10, 2}` будут указывать в одно и тоже место, так как их начала совпадают.
Также `a` будет иметь тип `int (*)[2]`. Таким образом несмотря на то, что `a` и `*a` совпадают, но `a+1` и `*a+1` совпадать уже не будут,  так как указывают на типы разных размеров. И сдвиг на 1 для этих указателей будет отличаться.
Теперь про оставшееся: `a` -- указатель, поэтому при конвертиации в указатель на `int` ((`int *)a`) указывать он продолжит на туже ячейку. И последнее: `&(a[0][0]) = &(*(a[0]+0)) = a[0]+0 = a[0]` так как `a[0][0]` -- нулевой элемент в этом массиве и его адрес это адрес начала всего массива.

Comment: Забыли про №5. `&(a[0][0]) == &(a[0]) == &a`.

Comment: Я хочу сказать, если a - указатель на первый элемент массива, то получается *a = 10 должно быть, но получилось так, что *a =a

Comment: "В С/C++ массив это обычный указатель на начало массива." - это совершенно не верно. В языках С и С++ массив не является указателем, а лишь неявно *приводится* в нему (в ряде оговоренных контекстов). Это совсем другое дело.